# Electron app is not showing notifications and I can't find my app on the windows notification center

Tags: notifications, electron, windows-11

I have an electron app. It used to show notifications as usual (Win11) but one day I switched them off from the notification tile. And now I cannot switch them back.

[Notification-example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mrxGp.png)

I tried to add the `app.on('ready', () => app.setAppUserModelId("Your.AppName"));`
and also I added on my package.json in the windows section on build
`"win": { "appId":"Your.AppName" }`

But nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

The quickest way to get the notifications back again with Windows 11 in 2023 (as this procedure seems to change every now and then):

1. Press `Win+R`, type `services.msc` and hit return to open the Services window
2. Scroll down to find the "windows push notifications user service" (there will be two "windows push notification" services, one of the is the "user service"), and stop it
3. Press `Win+R`, type `regedit` and hit return to open the Registry Editory
4. **Backup your registry using `File > Export...`in case something goes wrong** (this will not happen, but you know, just in case)
5. Navigate to the key `Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Notifications\Settings`
6. Within that key, you will find your Electron app id (the default ID would be `electron.app.Electron`)
7. Either set the `Enabled` attribute to `1` or better delete app's key. If you can't find your key and/or don't mind resetting your notification settings, you can even delete the entire `Settings` key from `Notifications`.
8. Navigate to `Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\PushNotifications\Backup`
9. You will find another key with the same app id there, delete that (again, if you don't mind resetting, delete `Backup` completely)
10. Close regedit
11. Open your Explorer, navigate to `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Notifications` (you can copy-paste that into the explorer's address bar)
12. Delete the three `wpndatabase.*` files you find there. These will be restored from what remains in the registry's `Backup` key when the service is restarted
13. close the Explorer again
14. In your services window, restart the stopped service
15. Notifications should now work again.

I tested this multiple times on my machine and can confirm that completely deleting the registry keys and the database files will definitely work in case you don't manage to find your app's id there.

**Edit addressing the actual problem of the question:**

To have your Electron app show up in the Windows notification center, two criteria must be met:

1. Your app must have an App-ID set with `app.setAppUserModelId("<myAppId>");`, so if you have that already, that's great.
2. The executable of Electron that starts your app must have a start menu shortcut. Depending on your tooling to build and install the application and how you start the app, this may happen automatically for you or not:

If you don't use anything apart from `electron` in your `dependencies` and start with `electron .`, I'm afraid I don't know of any way (yet) to get that to work with Windows 11. [The docs on that topic](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/notifications#windows) speak of adding the `electron.exe` from the local `node_modules` to the start menu, but I tested this in different combinations and could not get it to work. Notifications work, but the app doesn't appear in the notification center.

What will work, however, is to have a build tool like [`electron-forge`](https://www.electronforge.io/) or [`electron-builder`](https://www.electron.build/) build your application. They key is that they produce a [`Squirrel.Windows` distributable](https://github.com/Squirrel/Squirrel.Windows) which handles shortcuts and everything for you.

I'm personally using Electron Forge, so I only have experience with that. Still, these tools can produce a folder containing your built application and a complete installer package. Sending the executable from that build folder to your start menu or running the installer will set everything up. If it does not work immediately, you may have to clean your registry again using the above-mentioned steps.

If you don't use any of these tools yet, it *should* be relatively easy to integrate them into an existing application or, the other way around, set up an empty project with one of their initializers and integrate your existing code into that project. If you need help with that, open another question, and I'll gladly assist you.

Comment: You now if there is a way to add my app on the windows notification center? That's my main goal but I tested the fix and it worked!

Comment: Sure, I'll update the answer to include that. I was so carried away with that fix that I entirely forgot about that (bricked my own app's notifications reproducing your problem and had to find half of the registry stuff by myself)